# Is it possible to generate a script of the changes between 2 SQL snap shots?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The scenario is developer A creates a pull request for their work to our program, this may involve some SQL schema changes but these migrations are all covered for through our scripts.

The problem is with our database for the automation tests. At the moment scripts get run on the golden image of the database, to avoid complicated scripts for inserting test data. The users simply add the test data to the database through using the system (as this can get complicated). But until that pull request is completed, the other automation tests that run on the golden image may fail (As the database schema may be wrong). If we did this on a new db we aren't able to carry across that test data to the golden image on completion.

This is why I am asking if it possible to generate a script of the changes between 2 SQL snap shots? The changes would purely be extra data and not schema changes (as the snapshot would be after the developers scripts have been run).

Comment: Added the tag for sql-server.

Comment: Maybe you can give this a try https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/ Otherwise you can try rolling your own solution

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid I will look into that.